# urllib2 does not handle http NO_CONTENT (204) as a successful HTTPS response

Tags: python, https, azure-iot-hub

I am using an embedded python (2.4.3) in digi Connectport X4 here is the code to post to an Azure IoT Hub using HTTPS:

```
import urllib, sys, datetime, time
import urllib2
iot_device_id = 'HTTP_Device'
iot_endpoint = 'https://winiothub.azure-devices.net/devices/' + iot_device_id + '/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03'
sas_header = {'Authorization': 'SharedAccessSignature sr=winiothub.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FHTTP_Device&sig=o7dndsA%2FJOnkzYRUhqAwMrQXVhOTpIJqJqILyGDdQAc%3D&se=1522414643'}
while True:
    #try:
        body_data = { 'gateway_serial': '123', 'readingvalue':'66.00', 'date': str(datetime.datetime.now())}
        iot_request = urllib2.Request(iot_endpoint, str(body_data), sas_header)
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(iot_request)
        contents = resp.read()
        resp.close()
        time.sleep(1)
    #except:
    #    print 'error'
    #    time.sleep(1)
```

The code actually post the message to the hub, but is throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JeffreyBiesecker\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\NewGateAzure\NewGateAzure\NewGateAzure2.py", line 14, in ?
    urllib2.urlopen(iot_request)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 130, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 364, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 471, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 402, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 337, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\urllib2.py", line 480, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 204: No Content
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I get an error if running the code in the embedded Digi gateway or if I run in Python in Visual Studio using version 2.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

`urllib2.HttpError` includes the response code that's received. Because of this, you can catch the exception, test for 204, and continue safely if it is the case. Otherwise, you can handle (or rethrow) the exception.

```
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(iot_request)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    if e.code == 204: pass
    else: raise
```

Comment: Thanks, I will add this code for sure. Its good idea, I was wondering why 204 is an error in python 2.4, but in 2.7 it is not reported as an error. I tested this in Visual Studio. Thanks all for helping!!!!

Comment: I'm not sure why it's an error, it seems unintuitive - stepping through urllib2 in a debugger may be useful here.